# Swift date format

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I have a date in swift of type string with this format: "2020-06-20T15:40:22+02:00".
If I run the code:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter ()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date (from: (2020-06-20T15:40:22+02:00))
print (date)
```

I get:
2020-06-20 13:40:22 +0000
2 hours less. How can I apply offset to date?
Thank you.

Comment: A date is a point in time. `13:40:22 +0000` and `15:40:22 +0200` is the same. `print` shows dates always in UTC

Comment: And how can I print by adding the offset?

Comment: With a(nother) date formatter